# How to create table occurrences for filtered data..?

Tags: filemaker

I have a table called transactions.  Within that is a field called ipn_type.  I would like to create separate table occurrences for the different ipn types I may have.

For example, one value for ipn_type is "dispute".  In the past I would create a global field called "rel_dispute" and I would populate that with the value of "dispute".  Then I could create a new table occurrence of the transactions table, and make a relationship based on transactions::ipn_type = transactions::rel_dispute.  This way only the dispute records would show up in my new table occurrence.

Not long ago, somebody pointed out to me that this is no longer necessary, and there is a simpler way to setup such a relationship to create a new table occurrence.  I can't for the life of me remember how that was done, though.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a found set of only one type, you must either perform a find or use the Go to Related Record script step to show only related records. What you describe as your previous setup fits the latter.

The simpler way is to perform a find - either on demand, or by a script triggered OnLayoutEnter.

Answer (score 0):

The new 'easy' way is probably:

- using one base relationship only and
- filtering only the displaying portal by type.  This can be done with a global field, a global variable containing current display type.  Multiple portals with different filter conditions are possible as well.

~jens